# Angular.js pass filter to directive bi-directional ('=') attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I need to use `sublist` directive in few places of the page, and it should contain sometimes full `fields` list, but sometimes filtered. Here is my naive approach:

*HTML:*

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <sublist fields="fields" /> <!-- This one is OK -->
      <sublist fields="fields | filter: 'Rumba'" /> <!-- This one raises error -->
  </div>
```

*Javascript:*

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('sublist', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { fields: '=' },
            template: '<div ng-repeat="f in fields">{{f}}</div>'
        };
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.fields = ['Samba', 'Rumba', 'Cha cha cha'];
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/14/

When I try to use filter I'm getting this error:

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The *$digest iterations* error typically happens when there is a watcher that changes the model. In the error case, the isolate `fields` binding is bound to the result of a filter. That binding creates a watcher. Since the filter returns a new object from a function invocation each time it runs, it causes the watcher to continually trigger, because the old value never matches the new (See [this comment from Igor in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/Ib6YhFV3Xf4)).

A good fix would be to bind `fields` in both cases like:

```
<sublist fields="fields" /></sublist>
```

And add another optional attribute to the second case for filtering:

```
<sublist fields="fields" filter-by="'Rumba'" /></sublist>
```

Then adjust your directive like:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        fields: '=',
        filterBy: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="f in fields | filter:filterBy">'+
              '<small>here i am:</small> {{f}}</div>'
};
```

Note: Remember to close your `sublist` tags in your fiddle.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/6Xf9D/)

Comment: What if you potentially need multiple filters, sorts, etc? Is there a general solution to pass any general filtered/sorted list to a directive?

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky: At that point it's probably easier/necessary to do the heavy lifting in the directive link/controller function by injecting `$filter` there. (i.e. This Q&A context is the view, rather than the controller part of the MVC paradigm. The controller allows for much more complexity.) See [stackoverflow.com/a/14302334/2185093](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302334/2185093) for more info

Answer (score 1):

[Corrected Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/15/)

Check a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136504/using-filters-with-directives-in-angularjs).

In the fiddle you will need to have closing tags.
While you can still have self contained tags like the one you have.

```
 <sublist fields="fields" filter="'Rumba'"/> <!-- Tested in chrome -->
```

Comment: you can also have `filtered` data in your controller's scope. for that you will need to inject `'$filter' service` in your controller. included reference shows this.