# Using filter on directive attribute causes infinite loop in $digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

An attempt to use a filter on a directive with isolate scope:

```
<div tags="p.tags | refTags"></div>
```

Causes an infinite loop in the $digest cycle:

**This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each $digest cycle triggers a state change and subsequent $digest cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.**

```
.directive 'tags', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    scope:
        tags: '='
    templateUrl: 'partials/tags.html'


.filter 'refTags', ->
    (tags) ->
        ['a filtered', 'array of values']
```

**partials/tags.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag.tag}}</li>
</ul>
```

**p.tags in the controller**

```
p.tags = ['HTML5', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Angular JS', 'Backbone JS', 'Node JS', 'SASS + Compass', 'Oragami', 'Running', 'Cat Food', '#catfood']
```

Is this behavior normal?

1. Can a filter not be use on a value passing in to the isolate scope of a directive?
2. Is there a workaround for this? I need to filter the arrays values
3. Is there another solution with a different design?

Comment: That's not the complete refTags filter is it? Can you share that code?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is. It's coffeescript if that is causing any confusion

Comment: So your filter is actually returning an array with two items 'a filtered' and 'array of values'... how is it actually filtering those values?

Comment: `=` is a two way binding, how does it bind back if it is filtered?  I would imagine that it is binding to the p.tags, triggering the filter again, updating the value, then the binding is triggering the filter again... over and over

Comment: @Janathan Rowny no filtering is occurring I am just testing

Comment: @Janathan Rowny I see your comment below. I was unaware that angular was monitoring the model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is a directive problem but a filter problem. The goal of filter is to get an array as input and return another array based on some rules and conditions, where array items have the same structure as input.

The reason that causes an infinite loop in the $digest cycle is that in a filter, each digest cycle filter returns a different object that causes an additional cycle.

I suggest you to start by returning the same array, i.e. `input = output`. Check if all works as expected. After that add the relevant condition.

Comment: Agreed, if you're just returning an arbitrary array in filter, Angular doesn't recognize the model your filter is returning and digest keep on going.

Comment: Thank you Maxim and Jonathan. That clears things up. Excellent

Comment: @TaylorMac if you ever do a `console.log()` on a model, you'll see Angular assigns a bunch of stuff to it to keep track of it. That's another reason primitives are difficult for Angular because it can't assign its meta data to a string.

Answer (score 1):

[This question provides an actual workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17199892/2863530).

In short, pass the filter you want to use into your directive as well, and then use it there.

Comment: You should definitely link the original question/answer, but pull the salient details into this question and apply it directly to the problem presented here. Or, if the questions are identical, you can mark one a duplicate.