# How can I pass this value via attribute from the element to a custom directive that has dynamic filter?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to modify a directive that was custom built and I do not want to modify if possible the way it is currently structured.  I want to do exactly as stated in this question:

[Using Filters With Directives in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136504/using-filters-with-directives-in-angularjs)

instead of a single value I am having trouble with passing an orderBy.

```
 orderBy: 'text': true
```

I am getting an error telling me the `:` is not expected.  How can I pass this value via attribute from the element?

I also tried: `<a href="#" filter="'orderBy: \'test\': true'">item</a>`

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't entirely make sense. `orderBy` is not designed to filter items from a collection (i.e. it sorts). The directive you've linked to expects the `filter` attribute to be a predicate function that returns true if an item is to be filtered through. If you can elaborate with more code, that might help with an answer.

Comment: I'm trying to build a filter that's dynamic via an attribute.  I'm not sure how to explain it.  I'll write up some code sample and add to this question.  Thanks!